# Assigning "active" class to parent issue

Tags: jquery

I have a three level deep menu and what I want is that the active class goes on the parent li, this code below works on two levels, it shows the top menu item as active and the one below it, but when go to a page on the third level (ul ul ul li) all those list items in that last ul menu are active. Any ideas. I'm REALLY new to jQuery, so be kind ;-)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var path = location.pathname.substring(1);
  if ( path ) {
   $('#main_menu li a[href$="' + path + '"]').parents('li').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you show your mark up as well?

Comment: Its a bit hard to tell what the problem is using just that jQuery code, do you have the site online? Or can you show us an example of jsfiddle?

Comment: just add .last() after .parents()

Answer (score 1):

if you want to go a parent higher than the current parent you can do .parents('li').parents('li'). If the higher parent has a class e.g. `<li class="grandparents">` you can use .closest('.grandparents')

Comment: Then you can use .closest('li').closest('li'). .closest('li') selects the first li parent it finds. To find the parent li of that li you use another .closest('li')

Comment: Ah I didn't read it properly, I thought he wanted the sub sub menu item to have it.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Ah, you want the oldest ancestor so add last() after parents().

```
$('#main_menu li a[href$="' + path + '"]').parents('li').last().addClass('active');
```